# I am attempting to update the apex calendar automatically every minute using a procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

This code is a procedure to update the task every time a work shift as pass is scheduled and move it to another work shift and only ends when the task is closed. The scheduled for the work shift work this way:

```
1º:  7:00 to 15:00
2º: 15:00 to 23:00
3º: 23:00 to  7:00
```

But the problem I am having it this code is the part of DBMS_SCHEDULER, I am attempting to update the Apex calendar so it updates every minute but only updates when I run the first time, but when I attempt to run a second time, it gives this error:

> ORA-27477: "GERAL.TURNOS8" already exists

```
create or replace PROCEDURE                                                  
       check_task_turnos AS
CURSOR c_turnos
IS
SELECT TIPO,ID,estado,calendar_start,calendar_end
,Case
WHEN  to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 7 AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) < 15    

                 THEN 'apex-cal-yellow' 
                when to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 15 AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) < 23    

                 THEN 'apex-cal-yellow' 
                 when (to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 23  AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) < 24
                     OR
                     to_number(to_char(calendar_start,'HH24')) >= 0   AND to_number(to_char(calendar_end,'HH24')) <= 7)
                     THEN 'apex-cal-yellow' 
                 else null
                 end
FROM NVG_PASSAGEMTURNO
WHERE TIPO='To Do'
AND estado='Aceite';
BEGIN
FOR i IN c_turnos
      LOOP
    -- This table is for register reference that the task as changed the star time and end time
                INSERT INTO NVG_REGISTAR_PASSAGEM(passagem_id,
                                        start_date,
                                        end_date   
                                        )
                                VALUES(i.id ,  
                              i.calendar_start+(8/24) ,
                                    i.calendar_end+(8/24));
             -- update of start time and end time for updating the apex calendar
                UPDATE NVG_PASSAGEMTURNO
                SET  calendar_start =  i.calendar_start+(8/24)
                    , calendar_end   = i.calendar_end+(8/24)
                WHERE ID = i.ID;
                            END LOOP;
BEGIN
    DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB(
        job_name => 'turnos8',
        job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
        job_action => 'BEGIN
PKG_TURNOS.check_task_turnos;
END;',
        number_of_arguments => 0,
        start_date => TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-11-08 12:44:10.000000000 EUROPE/LONDON','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF TZR'),
        repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; INTERVAL=1',
        end_date => NULL,
        enabled => TRUE,
        auto_drop => FALSE,
        comments => '');
        END;            
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to *create* a job every time you run that PL/SQL piece of code. This is what you're currently trying to do:

> procedure > creates a job > calls the same procedure > creates the same job > calls the same procedure > creates the same job ...

You should:

- create the procedure (`check_task_turnos`)

  - don't create a job within!
- separately, create a job and schedule it to run every minute

  - it will call the `check_task_turnos` procedure, but it won't be creating the job all over again (besides, as you saw, it just won't work)